# How can I print the list of directory and sub-directory along with files inside sub-directory

Tags: php

Please see the following code which I have tried.

```
echo scanDirectoryImages("Images");


function scanDirectoryImages($directory, array $exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 
'gif', 'png'))
{

$html = '';
if (
    is_readable($directory)
    && (file_exists($directory) || is_dir($directory))
) {
    $directoryList = opendir($directory);
    while($file = readdir($directoryList)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $file;
            if (is_readable($path)) {
                if (is_dir($path)) {
                    return scanDirectoryImages($path, $exts);
                }
                if (
                    is_file($path)
                    && in_array(end(explode('.', end(explode('/', $path)))),   
$exts)
                ) {
                    $html .= '<img src="' . $path
                        . '" style="max-height:200px;max-width:200px" 
value="<?php echo basename($path)"/>  ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($directoryList);
}
return $html;
}
```

It is returning only the images from my sub directories but not the path of sub-directories what i actually want.
Also,I'am working on a server and not localhost which is creating a problem to set $path.
please help!!!

Comment: This is a recursive function. And sure it only lists the images if you call the function with the parameter ('jpeg','jpg','png','gif').
What you need to do is not just copy pasting code but instead understand it and modify it so that it fits your needs.
`if (is_dir($path)) {
                    return scanDirectoryImages($path, $exts);
                }` is a point of interest for you. Just to point you in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to show you a really easy way to get all of the files with a particular extension from a directory.

This makes use of various [Iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) and filters

the `FilterIterator::accept()` is the rule to which files are included in the iteration.

```
class ImagesOnlyFilterIterator extends FilterIterator
{
  function accept()
  {
    return in_array( strtolower( $this->current()->getExtension() ), array( 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp', 'tif', 'tiff' ), true );
  }
}

$path = '/foo/bar/whatever';

foreach( new ImagesOnlyFilterIterator( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path ) ) ) as $image )
{
  echo $image . PHP_EOL;
}
```

`$image` will actually be a [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) object, and will contain other various properties for you to use.

Comment: use strict mode for in_array.  https://eval.in/89008  / https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/1v7ek6/in_which_in_array_does_crazy_stuff/

Comment: @hanshenrik May not be an issue here as getExtension wrapped in strtolower can only return strings. But happy to add it.